# How to get value from the json response where a key is dynamic in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I want to extract a token from the the given below JSON response where the key of the token is dynamic. The key 57 is dynamic. it change every time. I know that how to extract value by given key but in my case the Key is dynamic. And based on the founded key I want to extract value.

On bottom of the question a complete JSON can be found, which is very shortened to better describe my problem.

```
{
  "message": "Too many sessions, log out please, on one of your devices",
  "active": {
    "57": [
      "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY5ODAiLCJlbWFpbCI6IkBAc3ViamVjdCsxQG9zYXQuY29tK29zYXQiLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiIxIiwiaXNzIjoibGVhcm5lciIsImlhdCI6MTcwMjAxOTcyNywiZXhwIjoxNzAyNjI0NTI3LCJwcm92aWRlciI6Ik9zYXQiLCJwaWQiOjV9.kXvAqJGqR9jjDTobzlwQ4k_sLl0aFWvEIeST93elODA",
      "Windows",
      "Chrome"
    ]
  },
  "status": "TOO MANY SESSIONS"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if attribute name is dynamic you can always go for [wildcard operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) like `*`

If you want to extract this guy:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY5ODAiLCJlbWFpbCI6IkBAc3ViamVjdCsxQG9zYXQuY29tK29zYXQiLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiIxIiwiaXNzIjoibGVhcm5lciIsImlhdCI6MTcwMjAxOTcyNywiZXhwIjoxNzAyNjI0NTI3LCJwcm92aWRlciI6Ik9zYXQiLCJwaWQiOjV9.kXvAqJGqR9jjDTobzlwQ4k_sLl0aFWvEIeST93elODA
```

The relevant [JsonPath](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath) query would be something like:

```
active.*.[0]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)